# How to install com.mysql.jdbc.Driver "Could not find driver with class name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, driver, confluence

I am setting up Atlassian Confluence and when it comes to choosing the database I stuck when I choose "use external Mysql DB"
I saw some tutorials, but for me it didnt work out the way it should work. I use ubuntu 12.04 Server and have mysql installed. Now I tried to run confluence with an external database and I need this connector driver to make it work.

I already did :

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-java
```

and I have java installed.

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
```

any help is upvoted fast :)

Comment: Add the mysql-connector.jar to your application classpath.

Comment: We have *no idea* what kind of app you're writing, which makes it hard to help you. Basically you need to put the relevant jar file on your classpath, but exactly how you do that will depend on what kind of app you're writing (local client app, web app etc).

Comment: can anyone explain me how it works with the classpath ? I downloaded the right driver.jar and put it in the location it should be. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have `mysql-connectorxx.jar` in your `class path` make sure its added the error you are facing will be resolved